# Using noConflict() with jquery libraries

Tags: javascript, jquery, libraries, conflict

I am using a jquery script for a dropdown menu and one for a image viewer. The two libraries conflict.

The following script is my libraries, Ive noted the 2 conflicting scripts. The first block is in the header of my script, the second is before my  tag (this is the only way the image slider script works).

```
      <!-- Drop down plugin (within the <head> tag -->
        <script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/superfish.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
        <script src="js/tms-0.4.1.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery/css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css"/>

        <!-- Conflicting code  -->
        <script src="jquery/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js"></script>
         <!-- Conflicting code ends  -->


    <!-- Content section <body> -->

    <!-- Image slider plug in (at the end of the <body> tag) -->

    <!-- Conflicting code  -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <!-- conflicting code ends -->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="slider/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="slider/js/jquery.kinetic.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="slider/js/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="slider/js/jquery.smoothdivscroll-1.3-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            // Initialize the plugin with no custom options
            $(document).ready(function () {
                // None of the options are set
                $("div#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll({
                    manualContinuousScrolling: true,
                    autoScrollingMode: "",
                    visibleHotSpotBackgrounds: "always"
                });
            });
        </script>
```

I have tried the following 2 scripts, The first one does nothing to resolve the conflict and the second causes the page not to load (it is a blank page with only the background color showing). There is a possibility I used the scripts incorrectly.

```
    <script src="prototype.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>

    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    // $j is now an alias to the jQuery function; creating the new alias is optional.

    $j(document).ready(function() {
        $j( "div" ).hide();
    });

    // The $ variable now has the prototype meaning, which is a shortcut for
    // document.getElementById(). mainDiv below is a DOM element, not a jQuery object.
    window.onload = function() {
        var mainDiv = $( "main" );
    }

    </script>
```

SCRIPT 2:

```
        <script src="prototype.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script>

        jQuery.noConflict();

        jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
            // You can use the locally-scoped $ in here as an alias to jQuery.
            $( "div" ).hide();
        });

        // The $ variable in the global scope has the prototype.js meaning.
        window.onload = function(){
            var mainDiv = $( "main" );
        }

        </script>
```

Comment: This is horrible, try to keep a minimum of order, and you'll only need to include jQuery once.

Comment: Are you aware that you're including exactly the same version of jQuery UI, twice?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario Note the `.custom.` in the name.  It's probably 2 different "custom" `ui` builds.  You can include just the components you want.

Comment: have you tried $(function($)({ var mainDiv=$("main");}) ?

Comment: do those libraries really _need_ different versions of jQuery? If so, you should really drop the library that uses the old version.

Comment: I didnt write any of the librarier, I havnt even edited them. They are both plug ins that told me to load those specific libraries. How can I go about getting rid of one of the libraries? And what exactly is disordered about this script? Im pretty new at jquery

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "does nothing to resolve the conflict" in the first example. But in the second example, are you sure it isn't, in fact, working perfectly? You have code there to hide all the divs on the entire page as soon as the document is ready ( `$( "div" ).hide();` ). That might well result in a page that looks empty except for background color.

Comment: I grabbed the noConflict() code from a website, Im actually not sure what it does. Could you explain to me whats going on in the script and how i could change it to just make the two libraries work together as opposed to making everything disappear?

Comment: Ah, I see. The noConflict() function removes its association with the variable "$" so that you can use some other library which tries to assign something to "$" (or so you can use more than one jQuery version on the same page, though that isn't recommended).

Comment: So you can either use the return value of the function to assign a new variable instead of $, or you can just use "jQuery" wherever you would have used "$". Or, as the sample code suggests, you can use a local scope where the jQuery object is passed into a method as "$". But when using noConflict() I prefer not to use $ as the variable at all, because it makes reading the code very confusing- people tend to expect "$" to always refer to the jQuery object, not to change meanings all over the place.

Comment: So i should change the noConflict() code to read "jquery" instead of "$"? How does that change anything?

Comment: What's going on (assuming there is actually a conflict here, I don't know prototype.js) is both libraries are assigning something to a variable called "$". Easiest solution is to load prototype.js, then load jquery.js, then call `jQuery.noConflict();` causing jQuery to avoid using "$", so from then on "$" no longer refers to the jQuery object. From that point on, anywhere you would ordinarily use "$" to refer to the jQuery object, use "jQuery" instead. Presumably prototype doesn't conflict with that. (You can do that even without noConflict(), because "$" is just shorthand for "jQuery" anyway)

Comment: The prototype/jQuery used in the bottom 2 scripts were examples from the website. What code would I have to put in there to fix the  <script src="jquery/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js"></script> and the <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>?  I dont know where these two libraries are conflicting (which variable they have in common)

Comment: Ok, so what you're saying is that the conflict is not between jQuery and prototype, it is between the multiple versions of jQuery? If both of these plugins are compatible with the the latest version of jQuery, it seems like you could avoid this whole issue. I don't think you really want to be trying to load 1.7.1, 1.10.1, and two different custom subsets of jQuery UI, all at once. Is there a reason you can't just download the latest versions of jQuery and jQuery UI, include each one only once in your page, and eliminate all the extra loading of jQuery?